# Find words from the list that contains at least 3 vowels

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regex in Python for finding every word from the list which contains at least 3 vowels (anywhere in word - not only consecutive). Found out how to do it for consecutive.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
text = 'Obvious Functionality When looking at the app directory, it should be obvious what kinds of things the application does.' 

def three_vowels(text):
    exp = r'\w*[aeiyouAEIYOU]{3}\w*'
    res = re.findall(exp, text)
    result = []
    marker = set()
    for l in res:
        ll = l.lower()
        if l not in marker:
            marker.add(ll)
            result.append(l)
    return result
```

Comment: Do you mean duplicates of vowels? What about parentheses like `r'(.*[aeiyouAEIYOU]){3}'`

Comment: No I want to find every word from txt file I have in which contains at least 3 vowels anywhere in that word. Till example - text: Obvious Functionality When looking at the app directory, it should be obvious what kinds of things the application does. And words with at least 3 vowels are: Obvious, Functionality, looking, directory, application.

Comment: Use `exp = r'\b(?:\w*[aeiyouAEIYOU]){3}\w*'`

Comment: Must it really be a regex? There are much easier ways to do that!

Comment: It might be better to split on whitespace, because regexp word-boundaries can't deal with hyphenated words and contractions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```py
\b(?:\w*[aeiyouAEIYOU]){3}\w*
\b(?:[a-zA-Z]*[aeiyouAEIYOU]){3}[a-zA-Z]*\b
```

A Unicode version would be

```py
\b(?:[^\W\d_]*[aeiyouAEIYOU]){3}[^\W\d_]*\b
```

where `aeiyouAEIYOU` can be replaced with a specific vowel set.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UFGFzy/1). Details:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:\w*[aeiyouAEIYOU]){3}` - three occurrences of:

  - `\w*` - zero or more word chars (digits, letters or `_`)
  - `[aeiyouAEIYOU]` - a vowel letter (`[^\W\d_]` matches any Unicode letter, and `[a-zA-Z]` matches an ASCII letter)
- `\w*` - zero or more word chars.

[A Python demo](https://ideone.com/zvyzvB):

```py
import re
rx = r"\b(?:\w*[aeiyouAEIYOU]){3}\w*"
text = "And words with at least 3 vowels are: Obvious, Functionality, looking, directory, application"
print( re.findall(rx, text) )
# => ['Obvious', 'Functionality', 'looking', 'directory', 'application']
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Wiktor! Really helpful.